# How to create a Shark query from a saved text file out of a RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, shark-sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a `JavaPairRDD<String, String> results` and I save it by calling:

```
results.saveAsTextFile("data")
```

Then I get files content like:

```
(www.abc.com,0.15712321 www.def.com,www.aaa.com,www.ccc.com)
```

Now, I want to create a table with three fields using Shark like:

```
url STRING  | rank DOUBLE | links STRING
www.abc.com | 0.15712321  | www.def.com,www.aaa.com,www.ccc.com
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I get for now is to convert `JavaPairRDD<String, String>` to `JavaRDD<String>`

```
JavaRDD<String> ret = results.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(Tuple2<String, String> pair) {
        return pair._1() + " " + pair._2();
    }
});
ret.saveAsTextFile("data");
```

Then I get my files like:

```
www.abc.com 0.15712321 www.def.com,www.aaa.com,www.ccc.com
```

Now, it is easy to create a table.